# Will updating a single document mulitple times in a batch possibly exceed Firestore's document write limitations?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have requirement where I have to remove and add array elements in the same document at the same time.

I am doing this by the following approach.

```
var doc = db.doc(path);
var batch = db.batch();

batch.update(doc, {list: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('post1')});
batch.update(doc, {list: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove('post2')});

batch.commit();
```

I am worried about the Firestore rule of 1 write per second per document.  Is there a possibility that can happen in this case and some writes can fail because of the `batch` from a single user.
I understand that this will not happen all the time but just want to know the possibility or way of best practices.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, there is a Firestore discussion group with Google staff watching it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss